# Need to take the values from slected checkboxes an place into an input file, separated by commas

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to take a series of selected checkboxes and create a comma separated list inside an input field. This is a bit beyond my jQuery skills.

Here is a sample of the HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Bill" id="CAT_Custom_173676_0" name="CAT_Custom_173676" />Bill<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="Dan" id="CAT_Custom_173676_1" name="CAT_Custom_173676" />Dan<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="Francis" id="CAT_Custom_173676_2" name="CAT_Custom_173676" />Francis<br />
```

I need to take the values from these checkboxes and insert them into this field

```
<input type="text" class="cat_textbox" id="CAT_Custom_172786" name="CAT_Custom_172786" maxlength="1024"  />
```

So, if all the checkboxes above are checked, the value of the input field would be "Bill,Dan,Francis".

This event can happen when the form is submitted.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [*map()*](http://api.jquery.com/map/) here to create a new jQuery object containing the values of checked checkboxes, then use [*get()*](http://api.jquery.com/get/) to obtain an array, then use [*join(",")*](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)<sup>nb</sup> to create a comma-separated string of those values:

```
var arr = ​$("input:checked").map(function () { return this.value; }​);
$("#CAT_Custom_172786").val(arr.get().join(","));
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/WLcNS/)

<sup>nb: you can actually omit *join()*, because an array converted to a string is automatically joined with comma separation. Personal preference comes into play here.</sup>

Comment: Andy, this is working great. Is there a way to make it dynamic, meaning as the user selects the checkboxes, the script updates the field?

Comment: @mmsa: I just added an example to the answer that does just that, applying a handler to the *change()* event.  Check out the example link, the code is all there for you.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the quick response. I'll need to look into the map() function!

Answer (score 1):

Also this will return all selected checkboxes that have the name "CAT_Custom_173676"

```
alert($("input[name=CAT_Custom_173676]:checked").map(function () {
return this.value;}).get().join(","));
```